# FBWebDialog without friend list

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

In my app I want to use `FBWebDialog` to send **"app request"** to the multiple users. But I dont want to select those users from the list which comes with the `FBWebDialog`. I just want to pass the friends from the `FBfriendpicker viewcontroller` to the `FBWebDialog` and send them from there. is it possible? How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the "to" parameter as documented in two pages referenced below, it will disable the drop down friend list and send to only one targeted audience

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

> Sending targeted requests
>
> You can filter the suggested list down or target one user. To filter
>   down the list you can pass in a parameter, suggestions that contains a
>   comma-separated list of friends to show in the selection. To target
>   one recipient, pass that user's ID in a to parameter

And also documented on request dialog page

> to A user ID or username, or a comma-separated list of them. These may
>   or may not be a friend of the sender. If this is specified by the app,
>   the sender will not have a choice of recipients. If not, the sender
>   will see a multi-friend selector and will be able to select a maximum
>   of 50 recipients. (Due to URL length restrictions, the maximum number
>   of recipients is 25 in IE7/IE8 when using a non-iframe dialog.)

Another documentation in games section of facebook with picture
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/requests/

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    // 2. Optionally provide a 'to' param to direct the request at
    @"286400088", @"to", // Ali
    nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrad  from 3.2 to 3.5.1 in part to allow me to use frictionless friend requests. The process works fine with:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:nil];

FBFrictionlessRecipientCache *friendCache = [[FBFrictionlessRecipientCache alloc] init];
[friendCache prefetchAndCacheForSession:nil];

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                                  message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I just posted an action - give me some points!"]
                                                    title:@"Get Points from your friends"
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                                      if (error) {
                                                          // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
                                                          NSLog(@"Error sending request.");
                                                      } else {
                                                          if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                              // Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                                                              NSLog(@"User canceled request.");
                                                          } else {
                                                              NSLog(@"Request Sent.");
                                                          }
                                                      }}
friendCache:friendCache];
```

This helps you to upgrade your Facebook sdk https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorial/iossdk/upgrading-from-3.2-to-3.5/

Comment: Hi death7eater, Please let me know if still any problem occurs. Thanks

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I already have 3.5 but in your solution I still have friend list under the FBWebDialogs. I dont want it. I just want to sent the requests to the facebook users which I selected from the friendpicker

Comment: Hi death7eater, if this code is not working then preety sure about retaining the friendCache. Might be it gets released before the FBWebDialogs tries to use it. Please let me know if still any problem occurs.